# GoogleMaps + c#

Tags: c#, google-maps

Estou tentando realizar um `request` no C# usando o pacote `RestSharp`, para obter informações de geolocalização passando o cep. O `request` ficou desta maneira:.

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + cep + "&key=" + key);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Porém eu só recebo `TimeOut`.

O estranho e que se eu executo essa URL no meu navegador, eu obtenho resultado.

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Configurou corretamente a `key` no console de desenvolvedor do google? Ativou a API de geocode e associou ela a `key`?

Comment: Sim, tanto que quando executo no navegador, a chamada funciona normalmente. Acredito que o problema seja em algo relacionada ao C#, porque fiz também usando angular e a mesma funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Dá uma olhada: [Chamar uma API Web de um cliente .NET (c#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente desta forma:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://maps.googleapis.com/");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

request.Resource = "maps/api/geocode/json?address={cep}&key={key}";
request.AddParameter("cep", cep, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.AddParameter("key", key, ParameterType.UrlSegment);

var response = client.Execute(request);
```

---

Outra forma, desta vez com `WebRequest`:

```
string url = $"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={cep}&key={key}";

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);

string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

response.Close();
```

Comment: Tentei desta forma, porém obtive o mesmo erro :/. Estou achando que isso só vai funcionar em JavaScript. tem sentido isso?

Comment: Não faz muito sentido, de uma das formas deveria funcionar!

Comment: Também penso assim, porém o mais estranho é que em angular funciona e quando jogo direto no navegador, também funciona

Comment: Adicionada na resposta uma outra alternativa!

Comment: Realmente é muito estranho. Também não rolou desta maneira...

Comment: Será que o URL fica mal formatado? Experimente obter a informação do URL que está a ser passado e confirme se está OK.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87845/discussion-between-guilherme-nunes-and-joao-martins).

Comment: Não se esqueça de marcar as respostas como úteis :)

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que em minha empresa o proxy estava bloqueando as chamadas realizadas por aplicações .NET!
Fiz o teste utilizando outra rede e funcionou normalmente.

Agradeço a todos por me ajudarem..